# Store object from local storage into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve a object from localstorage and trying to load it into a variable . How can i do this ? This is where i m stuck

```
   var messageStorage={};
    messageStorage.retrieve = function () {
        var storageString = localStorage.getItem(credentials.mobileNumber);
        var storageObj = JSON.parse(storageString);

        // whats should go here for messageStorage to be equal to storageObj
    };
```

On messageStorage.retrieve(); the variable messageStorage must contain the value from localstorage.

Comment: set the variable equal to the variable?? What you are trying to do seems strange.

Comment: seems to me that you most likely just need to return the storageObj value in your function. Try adding return storageObj;

Comment: @JanR will that make messageStorage = storageObj >??

Comment: no that will make the function messageStorage.retrieve() return the value of storageString

Answer (score 0):

with localStorage the data is actually stored as a string.
And you use JSON.parse to return the value

```
JSON.parse() Returns the Object corresponding to the given JSON text.
Example :
JSON.parse('{}'); // {}
    JSON.parse('true'); // true
    JSON.parse('"foo"'); // "foo"
    JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
    JSON.parse('null'); // null
```

But i saw that you want to return the variable. So what's the type of this variable ? Number, String, Boolean ? You can convert from String to what you need

Answer (score 0):

localStorage allows you to save only strings, so if you have to save an object you should save it as a JSON string or you can use this [library](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/offline-storage) to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

first of all we can't store objects to localstorage, only strings are allowed:

```
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(jsondata));

var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
```

now you have json data to parse it and get the value.